# Install new version of child dependency without changing parent dependency in node

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a node project `my-app` that depends on `my-other-lib` and `my-test-lib`, `my-other-lib` also has a dependency on `my-test-lib`.

This structure in node_modules looks like this:

```
my-app
├── my-other-lib@1.0.0
└── my-test-lib@1.0.0 (dev dependency)
    └── my-other-lib@1.0.0
```

`my-app` uses `my-other-lib` to do some stuff on the production app, `my-test-lib` is a framework of sorts to help with testing.  `my-test-lib` also makes use of `my-other-lib`.

I'm writing a test in `my-app` I want to add a bit of functionality to `my-other-lib` to help me in that test.  I don't need to change any code in `my-test-lib` to get this working, however I can't figure out how to get this dependency to update without bumping the dependency version in `my-test-lib` and releasing a new version of it.  It feels like I shouldn't have to do that.

If I release `my-other-lib@1.1.0`, then in my-app run `npm install my-other-lib@1.1.0`, I end up with this node_modules structure:

```
my-app
├── my-other-lib@1.1.0
└── my-test-lib@1.0.0 (dev dependency)
    └── my-other-lib@1.0.0
```

One thing that seems odd to me is that `my-test-lib` specifies the dependency as `my-other-lib: "^1.0.0"` which implies that it should be fine with using 1.1.0, but still both packages are installed in node_modules.

Is there a way to have `my-test-lib` use `my-other-lib@1.1.0` besides bumping the version in `my-test-lib` and releasing `my-test-lib@1.1.0`?  And if not, what is the point of specifying the `^` in versions listed in `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

`my-test-lib` is also a npm repository, same as my-app, so you actual structure is the following.

```
my-app
├── my-other-lib@1.1.0
└── my-test-lib@1.0.0 (dev dependency)
    └── my-other-lib@1.0.0
my-test-lib
└── my-other-lib@1.0.0
```

You need to have control over `my-test-lib` if you want to upgrade the packages.
let's say your folder structure looks like that:

```
workspace
├── my-app
└── my-test-lib
```

The process you should follow is the following (starting from workspace):

```
// go to your lib
cd my-test-lib
// upgrade my-other-lib
npm upgrade my-other-lib@^1.0.0
//increase your package.json version
// publish your new version
npm publish
// go back to your app
cd ../my-app
// upgrade my-test-lib
npm upgrade my-test-lib@^1.0.0
```

with this you should end up with the following structure:

```
my-app
├── my-other-lib@1.0.0
└── my-test-lib@x.x.x (dev dependency) (the new version you published)
    └── my-other-lib@1.1.0
```

Cheers.